# "ps -ef" returns different result when run within php script versus command line

Tags: php

In my test.php script I have this:

```
$out = exec ( 'ps -ef' );
echo $out;
```

Which outputs just this when I run "php test.php":

root     16682     2  0 Jan30 ?        00:00:00 [NFSv4 callback]

However, when I run "ps -ef" from the command line I get the usual long list of processes for all users..

Any ideas why the php script produces such different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
shell_exec ( 'ps -ef' );
```

This will return the entire output, whereas exec returns the last line of output:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php